# Commerce 1 find if Discount object is valid based on start/end dates (Twig)

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

In Twig, I want to find out if a discount is valid based on start/end date.  startDate and endDate don't seem to exist and I can't inspect the discount object by using the json_encode filter (returns {}).

How can we do this?

This is the code used to grab the discount object:

```
{% set discount = null %}
{% for d in craft.commerce.discounts %}
    {% if d.id == 1 %}{% set discount = d %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

name, description and enabled variables are available but no startDate/endDate.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to retrieve the discount model?

Comment: Sure it's in the description now.

Comment: @BradBell I forgot to mention you in my last comment but the code is now in the description.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Commerce 1, `craft.commerce.discounts` will return an array of Commerce_DiscountModel objects of all available discounts.

```
public function getAllDiscounts($criteria = [])
{
    $records = Commerce_DiscountRecord::model()->findAll($criteria);

    return Commerce_DiscountModel::populateModels($records);
}
```

`Commerce_DiscountModel` objects have a `dateFrom` and a `dateTo` property, which is probably what you're looking for.

Completely untested, but something like this:

```
{% set discount = null %}
{% for d in craft.commerce.discounts %}
    {% if d.id == 1 %}
        {% set discount = d %}
        {% if discount.dateTo > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' and discount.dateFrom < '2018-12-31 23:59:59' %}
            Matches!
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```